# What are the "certain objects" whose visibility is determined by the "view distance" setting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In the graphics settings, the description for "View distance" which has a slider for 1-100 is as follows:

> Adjusts the distance at which **certain objects** in the game will no
>   longer be visible. Increasing this will provide a richer and more
>   realistic environment at the expense of performance.

Does that include players or siege weapons? That is the most important to me. If I can see someone at a further distance in PVP it is **always** advantageous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've found at some experimenting:

- Large buildings like the PVP bridge gates and resource buildings
- Graphical detail of said buildings at a distance
- Smaller objects like boulders, plants, trees, etc. Sometimes they don't even load until I run into them!
- NPCs

What is most important is that the overall distance visible until that blue cloud covers everything is less. So in PVP, **if an enemy player is beyond that line, you can't see them** (or anything else, like siege weapons). If you care about PVP most, I would prioritize this setting at 100 and try to lower some other setting to mitigate the performance loss.

When I changed my settings from 100 down to 1, I noticed that about 20 meters of visible-area-cutoff.